# Magento backend problem

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I've just installed Magento on my website, but I can't access the backend.  The frontend works fine, but in the backend once I successfully login, it takes me to a blank screen.  I've read there's an issue with cookies and I've tried a range of commenting out lines in varien.php, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `/var/log/exception.log` and check for any errors.

Alternatively in `index.php` just before the last line:

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

put this

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It should throw some sort of error now, and go from there.

Comment: After checking for errors, the problem was that the php.ini file only allocated 24MB of memory.  It says Magento needs at least 64, but I set it to 32 and all is fine now.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: I have set mine to 512M in order to have a decent speed.

Answer (score 0):

Blank screen is almost always a PHP error of some kind (as opposed to a Magento Exception).  Check/turn-on your PHP error logs and you should find the error you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For the cookies issue, install *and* access Magento using ht*p://127.0.0.1/magento/ instead of ht*p://localhost/magento/

Answer (score 0):

Please clear var/cache/ folder and var/session/ folder and refresh .